# RSelenium - rsDriver(browser = "firefox") -> Conection Refused

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I'm trying to use Selenium for the first time in my computer. But I'm having an error in the first line:

My code:

```r
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox")
```

Error message:

```
 checking Selenium Server versions: BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
 BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD checking chromedriver versions: BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
 BEGIN: DOWNLOAD BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD checking geckodriver versions:
 BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD BEGIN: DOWNLOAD BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD checking
 phantomjs versions: BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD BEGIN: DOWNLOAD BEGIN:
 POSTDOWNLOAD
 
    [1] "Connecting to remote server"
     Could not open firefox browser.
     Client error message:
     Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4567: Conection Refused
     Check server log for further details.
     Warning message:
     In rsDriver(browser = "firefox") : Could not determine server status.
```

My OS is Linux Mint, 19.3, Cinnamon.

I installed selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar and geckodriver-v0.26.0

Answer (score 1):

Try this FIRST:

```
suppressWarnings(tryCatch(rm(remDr),error=function(e){}))
suppressWarnings(tryCatch(rD),error=function(e){}))
gc()

#relaunch
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox")
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate("https://www.duckduckgo.com")
```

Alternatively this:

```
#make sure lsof is installed on your system: 
#sudo apt-get install ssh-askpass lsof

system("kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:4567 -sTCP:LISTEN)")
#might need to be run sudo depending on your system
system("sudo kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:4567 -sTCP:LISTEN)")

#relaunch
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox")
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate("https://www.duckduckgo.com")
```

**If none of that works, you may have installed the wrong geckodriver.** Uninstall geckodriver from linux (`sudo apt-get remove geckodriver --purge`) and uninstall RSelenium from R (`remove.packages("RSelenium")`). **Then DO NOT re-install geckodriver**, but make sure you have all firefox dependencies (run sudo apt-get install firefox). Re-install RSelenium (in R), then try re-launching again without manually downloading geckodriver. In this way **RSelenium will automatically download the correct geckodriver version**.

Comment: Thanks! But didn't work. I tried everything. At the first code, I had this error `> suppressWarnings(try(rD))
Error in try(rD) : object 'rD' not found
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells  953575 51.0    1934678 103.4  1333855 71.3
Vcells 2024328 15.5    8388608  64.0  5794869 44.3`

Comment: At the second code, I had `> system("kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:4567 -sTCP:LISTEN)")
sh: 1: kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus]
> #might need to be run sudo depending on your system
> system("sudo kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:4567 -sTCP:LISTEN)")
sudo: no one tty present and any programm of askpass especified`

Comment: After I remove and re-install everything as you said, I had the same massages.

Comment: Just to know, I also tried to install geckodriver following this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/870530/how-to-install-geckodriver-in-ubuntu

Comment: After I run suppressWarnings(try(rD)) again, I had `$client
[1] "No sessionInfo. Client browser is mostly likely not opened."

$server
PROCESS 'file25e24b4e1377.sh', finished.`

Comment: Those arent errors, the rD warning just warns you that it didnt previously exist. The kill warning is just a notifier on how to use it. Looks like you may need to install askpass and lsof: ``sudo apt-get install ssh-askpass lsof``. Try running that then launching again even if you get warnings/errors.

Comment: Also manually downloading and installing geckodriver is not a requirement if you have firefox downloaded. RSelenium will do this for you automatically

Comment: I changed the ``rm(rD)`` part slightly. Try that again first

Comment: About `sudo apt-get install ssh-askpass lsof` : ssh-askpass is already the newest version (1:1.2.4.1-10); `suppressWarnings(tryCatch(rD),error=function(e){})`:
Error in suppressWarnings(tryCatch(rD), error = function(e) { : 
  unused argument (error = function(e) {

Comment: lsof is already the newest version (4.89+dfsg-0.1).

Comment: Do I need install a Docker?

Comment: No dont need docker

Comment: @About ``sudo apt-get install ssh-askpass lsof : ssh-askpass is already the newest version (1:1.2.4.1-10); suppressWarnings(tryCatch(rD),error=function(e){}): Error in suppressWarnings(tryCatch(rD), error = function(e) { : unused argument (error = function(e) { –:``these are fine, continue launching

Comment: You've rebooted the computer I assume? That also clears ports. Try using ``rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=5111L)``

Comment: Can Java be the problem?

Comment: Same problem from my side `Selenium message:Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'porthos', ip: '192.168.1.100', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-91-generic', java.version: '11.0.11'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Could not open firefox browser.`